# TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'NativeClipboard_1.default.getString')

Tags: react-native, expo

I want to use `@twotalltotems/react-native-otp-input` in my `expo` project. I have go through with the documentation of `@twotalltotems/react-native-otp-input` But I'm getting this error. I have tried the solution from https://github.com/tttstudios/react-native-otp-input/issues/87

But none of that is worked for me!
[image]

Comment: I am having this issue today with Expo SDK 44, react native 0.64, and react-native-otp-input@1.3.11 I've installed the community clipboard package and cleared the expo cache multiple times but still the issue persists.

Comment: @Gaurav 1st Solution was worked for me. Did you try this??

Comment: yes it kind of works but with a LogBox warning that the clipboard was moved from react-native.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this

1: install `yarn add @twotalltotems/react-native-otp-input@1.3.7`

2: install `yarn add @react-native-community/clipboard`

3: Run `expo start -c` to clear the cache

Answer (score 4):

For people using this package `@twotalltotems/react-native-otp-input` with `expo`, remember expo is not compatible with Clipboard package but itself offers another package `expo-clipboard`. So you've two ways -

1. either use `@twotalltotems/react-native-otp-input` version 1.3.7 (it uses `clipboard` from `react-native` but throws a warning that Clipboard is deprecated.)
2. Or you can hack around by copying this package code (from GitHub or node-modules) into your codebase. Create your own component and install `expo install expo-clipboard` and replace default clipboard import with `import Clipboard from 'expo-clipboard';` in index.js file. Note - Do not make this change in node-modules as any package update will nullify your hack.

Answer (score 1):

As per documentation you have to install @react-native-community/clipboard as a dependency it would fix your issue just do
npm install --save @react-native-community/clipboard

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to override this component by these steps:

Clone this file @twotalltotems/react-native-otp-input/dist/index.js

Replace these lines:

```
  import Clipboard from '@react-native-community/clipboard';

  import styles from './styles';

  import { isAutoFillSupported } from './helpers/device';

  import { codeToArray } from './helpers/codeToArray';
```

to

```
import * as Clipboard from 'expo-clipboard';

import styles from '@twotalltotems/react-native-otp-input/dist/styles';

import { isAutoFillSupported } from '@twotalltotems/react-native-otp-input/dist/helpers/device';

import { codeToArray } from '@twotalltotems/react-native-otp-input/dist/helpers/codeToArray';
```

and change
`Clipboard.getString() to Clipboard.getStringAsync()`

Then use your own component instead of. it should work as expected

if you are using typescript, add this `// @ts-nocheck` on top.

Answer (score 1):

For Window users clear your cache. Mostly this issue pops up when you install a new dependence in my case i installed `@react-native-community/clipboard` since it was required by `@twotalltotems/react-native-otp-input`.

After the installation the error pops up. So what did I do?

I cleared my cache by running `yarn cache clean` and then restarted my PC everything went back to normal.

Answer (score 1):

check the package.json file and look for the "@twotalltotems/react-native-otp-input": "^1.3.7",
delete the caret so it doesn't keep the current minor it would look like this "1.3.7", then npm install/yarn add
check [What's the difference between tilde(~) and caret(^) in package.json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22343224/whats-the-difference-between-tilde-and-caret-in-package-json)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).